# problem in executing if-else loop inside a try catch block

Tags: java, netbeans-8

On button click event it is not entering if loop but directly entering else loop.
Output is always the same that is 1.

There is a text field called secret share and a button.
when the secret share field is null we want to execute if loop
and when it is not null we want to execute else loop.
but it is always executing else loop only.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if(jTextField_getSecretShare3.getText()== null)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "0");
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "1");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no "if loop" or "else loop". "if" and "else" are *statements*, not loops. Loops are things like "for" and "while".

Comment: i think `jTextField_getSecretShare3.getText()` never returns null. Use a debugger to find out what is returned by  `getText()`

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: maybe the return value of the textfield is not null, but an empty string? Try to check with `jTextField_getSecretShare3.getText()== null || jTextField_getSecretShare3.getText().isEmpty()`

Answer (score 1):

[`getText`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()) is inherted from `JTextComponent`, and it never returns `null`. If you want to check for an *empty* JTextField, use [`isEmpty`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) (or, depending on your use case, [`isBlank`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank())):

```
if (jTextField_getSecretShare3.getText().isEmpty())
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "0");
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "1");
}
```

Note that you could do that in a single statement using the conditional operator (`? :`):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, jTextField_getSecretShare3.getText().isEmpty() ? "0" : "1");
```

Comment: @Sunchezz - Big time, updated! :-) Or `isBlank` depending on the OP's use case.